# unable to get API data on Angular

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework

I have uploaded my project to Heroku which have Django Rest as backend and Angular as frontend. Everything is working fine locally except I am unable to get API request (branches/) in https://branches-front-shiv.herokuapp.com/.

[image]

So in above picture as you can see there is blank output in the left side which is from branches-front-shiv.herokuapp.com and in right side we have table, pagination controls. I don't have any errors it's just a blank page (because of these API request I guess). I don't know how to solve it.

**components.ts**

```
export class ShowBranchesComponent implements OnInit {

  branches: any = [];
  branchName: any; // any
  p: number = 1;

  options = ["All Cities", 'MUMBAI', 'KOLKATA', 'DEHLI', 'CHANDIGARH', 'NOIDA']
  selected: any = "All Cities";
  selectedData: any;

  constructor(private service: ShareService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.refreshBranchList();
    this.service.getBranchList().subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.branches = response;
      this.selectedData = this.branches;
    });
  }
```

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ShareService {
  readonly APIUrl = "https://branches-shiv.herokuapp.com";
  readonly PhotoUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getBranchList(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.APIUrl + '/branches/');
  }

  getAllNames(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.APIUrl + '/branches/');
  }
}
```

**App.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BranchesComponent } from './branches/branches.component';
import { ShowBranchesComponent } from './branches/show-branches/show-branches.component';
import { ShareService } from './share.service'

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';
import { Ng2OrderModule } from 'ng2-order-pipe';
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';
import { NgMultiSelectDropDownModule } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BranchesComponent,
    ShowBranchesComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    Ng2SearchPipeModule,
    Ng2OrderModule,
    NgxPaginationModule,
    NgMultiSelectDropDownModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [ShareService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

*mention any other code file you want to see in comment section.* Thankyou.

**app.components.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular';
}
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/angular'));
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname +
        '/dist/myapp/index.html'));
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BranchesComponent } from './branches/branches.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'branches', component: BranchesComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: share  app.component.html or the html file where you have put <router-outlet></router-outlet>

Comment: in localhost you are showing `/branches/` and in Heroku you are on `/` path

Comment: but after going to /branches/  it is saying not Found which is obvious because I don't have any '/branches/'  API request for some reasons.

Comment: I think your app is totally fine, you just have to add a router link to `/branches/` in app.component.html

Comment: please explain in code.

Comment: if you have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in `app.component.html`, then add a router-link -> `<a router-link="/branches">Branches</a>` in `app.component.html` to load `/branches` route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **app.routing.ts** you are defining *branches* as urls path,

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'branches', component: BranchesComponent },
];
```

**service.ts** there is also reference `/branches/` for getting API request, which might over writing your urls paths.

Try changing one of them to empty string:

```
const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', component: BranchesComponent },
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define rules to rewrite URL and point to index.html in your reverse proxy server.
Angular is a SPA with its own router. You need to redirect all requests to index.html which will deal with the routing.

Comment: Any example would be a grate help.

Comment: Depends on your reverse proxy. Is it nginx or apache?

Comment: I'm not using these technologies. It was just a simple project so. Anyway other I can get those request. I mean it is working fine in local host the only problem with Heroku server when it online.

Comment: I need more details on how you did setup the app on Heroku. How is it served? What does the routing look like?

Comment: I added a routing file from my code please take a look it is in end of the question.